# Specify ghc options at command line via cabal (cabal-install) without editing .cabal files of packages

Tags: haskell, vector, ghc, cabal, compiler-flags

When I install `vector` with:

```
cabal install vector
```

I get lots of `SpecConstr` limit warnings which would go away if I could specify `-fspec-constr-count=SOMETHING-HIGHER`.

1. Would

   ```
   cabal install vector -fspec-constr-count=HIGH
   ```

   work?
2. If `X` depends on `vector`, is there a way to say in `X.cabal` I depend on `vector` with preferably (in case `X` is not yet already installed) `-fpsec-constr-count=HIGH`?
3. Is `vector` still maintained or is there now a more recommendable alternative?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass extra options to programs run by Cabal by using `--PROG-options=OPTS`.

```
cabal install vector --ghc-options=-fspec-constr-count=HIGH
```